# Bicycle Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a survey, pupils were asked if they owned a bicycle.

Results:

3/8 of the pupils said ‘Yes’.

5/8 of the pupils said ‘No’.

46 more pupils said ‘No’ than said ‘Yes’.

Altogether, how many pupils were in the survey?

How do you work this out? I know should always find 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let there are  $8r$ pupils all together,

$\frac38\cdot8=3r$ pupils said 'yes' and $\frac58\cdot8=5r$ pupils said 'no'

$\implies (5r-3r)=46$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $2r = 46$ $r = 23$